# Codeigniter Sessions Swapped Between Users

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am facing an issue on one of my clients' websites, where it seems two users' sessions are being swapped. I am using CodeIgniter and have the following configuration:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Yesterday I was facing an issue where one of the users was having his session re-generated on every page. I incremented the size of the User-Agent database field in the sessions table, and switched match_ip above to TRUE, as an extra precaution.

Today, it seems two users are logging in, and they are each having the "Welcome X" message in the header as the name of the other person. Unfortunately, I only get this information from my client, so I am unable to debug the issue or replicate it on my machine, as sessions seem to be working fine for me (locally and online).

Does anyone have any suggestion or insight on how I could further debug, knowing my circumstances, or on what the issue might be? I tried adding:

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->session->sess_create();
```

On user logging, but I am not sure if that could be the issue.

I also of course double-checked that there is nothing wrong with my actual login code... However, it is simply retrieving email+password from POST and finding a matching record in the database, the usual procedure.

Comment: Any special characters in username or in pass? It could change MySQL SELECT result.

Comment: There are no special characters in the username beyond underscore and dot (.) usually found in e-mail addresses. I am not sure about the password though since it is encrypted in the database. I think if it was so, they wouldn't be able to login at all since the query wouldn't find any matching record in the database however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is a strange issue, **put up a longer encryption key and encrypt your cookies** and see if they have issues again.

These are my settings I use on many websites and haven't had this issue (**Encryption key, encrypting cookie and expire on close**).

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'dkfhlgsugT&(657865876t0967(*)&^)(*&*(&$^&%#%^#_)(+JKBVKHJFDC^*%VR^C@%C^';

$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

and make sure you destroy your sessions on user **logout page** and also login page (as you stated):

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Comment: I am using quite a long encryption key as well. I will add encryption on cookie however.

Comment: This may be caused by two users using the same computer and when they logout, the sessions and cookies aren't destroyed correctly.

Comment: I do not believe the two users who got mixed up were using the same computer or are even related at all. I am waiting for feedback from the client to see if the issue is still showing up.

Comment: Issue doesn't seem to have shown up again. I have a strong feeling it was from: $this->session->sess_destroy(); (I wasn't destroying session before creating a new one before on login). Hopefully it is indeed resolved. Thanks for the help.